# Kafka stream doesn't return the correct message

Tags: apache-kafka

I am fairly new to Apache Kafka.

The app I am building has a topic 'A' for incoming jobs.
a job is a simple json
{"jobId":1 , "processedIds": [] , "ids":[1,2]}

each job's id's are then processed in a listener listening on topic 'A'

so, for example for the job above,
id 1 will be processed and the following message will be sent to topic 'A':
{"jobId" 1, "processedIds": [1] , "ids":[1,2]}

to populate the processedIds, I get the job from the KafkaStreams store by id and append the new processedId to the existing set.

However,
When I get the job from the Kstream after adding a processedID, the job returned is the initial job
{"jobId":1 , "processedIds": [] , "ids":[1,2]}

Would anyone know why? and this seems to happen sporadically, so sometimes it works just fine.

consumer config properties :
auto.offset.reset - earliest 
auto.commit.interval.ms - 1000

I tried different values for the interval by increasing and lowering it.
I also tried auto.offset.reset -latest

This is while I am running an integration test.For another test in the same app I get an InvalidStateStoreException.I know that the error needs to be caught and the access to the store needs to be retried as it could be unavailable during a rebalance.I also see that if I run the test on debug, it passes the test.So I assume it could also be some sort of timing issue?

```
Producer<String, Request> p = new KafkaProducer<String, Request>(props,new StringSerializer(),new JsonSerializer<Request>());   

//for each id in job    
Request r1 = new Request();
r1.setId("1");
r1.setJobId("1");
r1.setId(1L);
future = p.send(new ProducerRecord<String, Request>("ResultsTopic",r1.getId(),r1));
future.get();

Request r2 = new Request();
r2.setId("2");
r2.setJobId("1");
r1.setId(2L);
future = p.send(new ProducerRecord<String, Request>("ResultsTopic",r2.getId(),r2));
future.get();

p.flush();
p.close(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

//Kafka listener method for incoming jobs topic - "ResultsTopic"
@Autowired
KafkaStreams all_job_stream;
String jobId = request.getJobId();
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Job> store = all_job_stream.store("AStore", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());   //this throws a InvalidStateStoreException


Job job = store.get(jobId); //if I add a sleep before this the test passes

job.getCompletedResponseIds().add(request.getIds());

jobKafkaTemplate.sendDefault(partitionSelectionStrategy.getPartition(job), job.getId(),job);
```

I wonder if these two issues are related.

I have also added a countdown latch between the requests.
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do... Maybe you can share some code?

Comment: are you using Kafka-stream state stores ? From my understanding, you're basically recovering the original message, not the modified one. You may need to publish some code snippet indeed

Comment: yes, I am using the kafka-stream state stores.This is when I am trying integrations tests using embedded kafka cluster.Editing the original question with a stripped down code of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think I have a clue of what is happening. The first request is sent by the producer.But it isn't available to the consumer immediately.I have linger.ms set to 1.